# How are doubles converted to string with retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

We have the following method declaration in our api:

`Call<WeatherResult> getWeatherPredictions(@Query("lat") double latitude, @Query("lon") double longitude);`

Now the API that we consume is rather "simple" as it just sends back `400`s when its not happy with the given latitude or longitude. They could easily "patch" the values on their end but they won't.

My question now is, does anybody know how `double`s are converted by retrofit2? I quickly looked at the source code but kind not find anything there.

Comment: `String.valueOf` ? or `"lat="+value;`

Comment: Thats why I'm asking, because `String.valueOf(0.1200)` returns `0.12` which might not be what you want because of API restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question now is, does anybody know how doubles are converted by
>   retrofit2?

They are using   `String#valueOf(Object)`. Query is an interface. You can find it [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/http/Query.java). The documentation states:

> Values are converted to strings using {@link String#valueOf(Object)}
>   and then URL encoded.

Comment: Thanks. Now I kind of feel bad for not reading the documentation properly